# Substituir strings do nomes de arquivos com Windows PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Como substituir strings do nomes de arquivos em lote usando o `Windows PowerShell`?

Ex: Substituir o carácter " " pelo "_" de todos os arquivos de uma pasta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para fazer isso pode-se utilizar o seguinte comando:

```
Dir -R | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name -replace " ","_" }
```

que no caso irá buscar e renomear arquivos de forma recursiva (devio ao **-R**).
Também é possível filtrar arquivos que serão renomeadas por extensão utilizando um parametro `*.cpp`

```
Dir -R *.cpp| Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name -replace " ","_" }
```